# kernel, glibc, and userland

Tags: kernel, debian, glibc

My goal is to run a newer kernel Linux 3.4 with a debian (squeeze) userland.

Debian's [KernelFaq](http://wiki.debian.org/KernelFAQ) simply says that we grab the newest pristine kernel from kernel.org and configure and compile it manually.

However, in the [glibc documentation](http://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/FAQ#What_version_of_the_Linux_kernel_headers_should_be_used.3F), it states that:

> The GNU C library runs without problems on kernels that are older than the kernel headers used [during compilation].  The other way round (compiling the GNU C library with old kernel headers and running on a recent kernel) does not necessarily work as expected.

Since the kernel API is fairly stable from 2.6.32 to 3.4, I can probably get away with just compiling the 3.4 kernel; but, I wonder if this still leaves potential issues.

Is the more correct way of doing this to recompile eglibc 2.11.3-4 against my Linux 3.4 (or newer) headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder if this still leaves potential issues.

You didn't quote the next paragraph from the glibc wiki:

> ... does not necessarily work as expected. For example you can't use new kernel features if you used old kernel headers to compile the GNU C library.

In other words, your existing glibc build (and the rest of userland) will work *just fine* on the new kernel, but glibc may not use all the latest features that the kernel provides.

Comment: Yes, but what about changes/bugfixes to existing kernel features?  Could these changes cause unexpected behavior in userland applications?

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I realize that the point is moot.  Recompiling glibc against a new kernel headers will not alter kernel implementation.  A userland application that breaks because of changes in kernel is the result of incompatibility with the kernel -- and glibc has nothing to do with that.